# How to change texture UVMapping on the fly?

Tags: three.js, textures

I have rectangle geometry (W x H size) and texture (2*W x H), and i need to show only half of it:

```
    ...
    var pageGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(pageWidth, pageHeight, 1, 1);
        var texture = someTexture;
        pageGeometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
        pageGeometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
            new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 1),
            new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0),
            new THREE.Vector2(1, 0),
            new THREE.Vector2(1, 1)]);

        var page = new THREE.Mesh(
            pageGeometry,
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: options.background,
                map: texture
            })
        );
```

It works, but ater some rotation (90 deg) i need to change the texture offset:

```
    page.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
    page.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),
        new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0),
        new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 1)]);
    page.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: options.background,
        map: textureNext
    });
```

but it doesn't work, offset of the remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this :
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

namely: 
`geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;`

Hope this helps but whatever maybe not works in your source code, you will for sure need to set this update-Flag after changing UV-Coordinates, I think.